# file_get_contents not working on my server

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have created two files, one on my wamp server (localhost), and one on my ovh.com private space. Both files contains only this content :

```
echo $search = file_get_contents('https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/game/by-summoner/19319907/recent?api_key=6fa73a35-6477-412d-97a6-b6739cb6cf1b');
```

On my server, there is some wrong characters, like â, þ or ¬, etc ...

How it can happends, and how can I resolve this ?

Edit: It's not about files ! It's about servers, cause files are exactly the same !
You can check the good one here : http://www.dietadom.fr/test.php, and the bad one here : `http://82.124.50.144/test.php`

headers from requests to both those scripts:

Working:

```
curl -I  http://www.dietadom.fr/test.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: clusterBAK=R1564861669; path=/; expires=Wed, 19-Mar-2014 16:38:43 GMT
Date: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 15:19:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: cluster=R1649376954; path=/; expires=Wed, 19-Mar-2014 16:32:22 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.24
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Not Working:

```
curl -I http://82.124.50.144/test.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 15:19:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1d PHP/5.4.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12
Content-Type: text/plain; charset: UTF-8
```

Comment: Files are exactly the same ... UTF-8 (without BOM)

Comment: The encoding header sent by the server is wrong, not the file encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the default character encoding header provided by your two servers is different. You can fix this by changing the server configurations to make sure they both have the default. Or you can modify your script to over-ride this, adding a content encoding header will make this consistent.

If you modify your PHP file for UTF-8 plain test content the line would be

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
```

Your source URL is responding with:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

retrieved using

```
curl -I https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/game/by-summoner/19319907/recent?api_key=6fa73a35-6477-412d-97a6-b6739cb6cf1b
```

hence how I know it's UTF-8 encoded.

**EDIT**

Having checked against your server I can see the header for an error page of:

```
curl -I http://82.124.50.144/404.html
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 17:24:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1d PHP/5.4.12
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The last line showing me the default charecter encoding is iso-8859-1, which means that the `utf-8` data from your source is being transmitted with the wrong encoding. Adding the correct header line to your script should fix the issue.

You could change your apache server configuration by adding `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` as well.

I'm sure that your issue is with character encoding, so you should look into that.

Comment: It's not about files, it's about servers. Files are exactly the same ! Same file should give the same result, but not here cause of servers !!!

Comment: That's correct, the servers are configured differently, but because I know nothing about your servers I've offered solution in your php. you could alternatively make sure that the content encodings on your servers were set to be the same.

Comment: We need to know more about your server config then. There is nothing wrong with the script, as you say.

Comment: My server is a wampserver with default config, only php_openssl added to accept https request. I don't know really about my ovh server, but you can see the offer here : http://www.ovh.co.uk/web-hosting/, that's personal package

Comment: wamp isn't my platform, so I have to bow out here, could be something in windows causing the utf8 to be munged. OVH looks like a linux server. However it certainly looks like a content-encoding issue, if that helps you look further. One thing, are you running your script from a web page or from a command line?

Comment: I've just spotted my header line was wrong. Maybe try my amended line `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: I'm running my script from a web page. And your script is not working more ^^, it only change char by ? or empty space.

Comment: It still looks very much like the default character encoding on your test server is wrong compared to the contents you are getting form the API. I can't help further than that I'm afraid.

Comment: i will try my script on an other server and test, if it's ok, then i will be happy even if i don't get the answer ^^. Thank for your time anyway !